# Salesforce - Time Dependant Workflows

Tags: workflow

I am currently creating some time dependant workflows and was wondering how the evaluation criteria - on the time dependent workflow action works.

Are time dependant workflows re-evaluated on the workflow rule criteria before they are sent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's only available upon record creation or modification. So let's say you go through and have it based on the CloseDate field and you want an email sent 5 days before CloseDate.

I start a close date of 2/16/2012 which would fire the email on 2/14/2012. On 2/13/2012 I change my close date to 2/14/2012. This would not fire the email since it would not be within the criteria any longer.

Comment: Excellent just what I was looking for. Cheers